# need SAS to analyze data within a group

Tags: sql, sas

I'm trying to analyze some grouped data in SAS 9.3. This is how its structured:

```
VisitID     PtCls       CC       DX
A             E         NULL           NULL
A             E         CP             NULL
A             E         CP             NULL
A             I         CP             HEART ATTACK
A             I         CP             HEART ATTACK

B             E         shortbreath    NULL
B             E         shortbreath    NULL
B             E         shortbreath    NULL
B             E         shortbreath    NULL

C             I         CHECKUP   DEFICIENT FE
C             I         CHECKUP   DEFICIENT FE

D             U         NULL      NULL

E             E         NULL      NULL
E             E         CP        NULL
E             O         CP        POOR SURGERY
E             O         CP        POOR SURGERY
E             O         CP        POOR SURGERY

F             E         NULL      NULL
F             E         NULL      NULL
F             E         NULL      NULL
```

With each unique `visitID` being a single patient visit (so 6 visits total in this set)

I need to count the number of visits where:

- DX and CC are always null (never have a real value in there) - 2
- CC is null, but DX is NOT null - 0
- PtCls is 'E' at least once within the visit - 4
- PtCls class is NEVER 'E' within the visit - 2

Plus, how to remove a group where `Ptcls` is never `E`

Any ideas? I don't even know where to start!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `proc sql` and nested aggregation aggregation.  First define the conditions at the visit level:

```
select VisitID,
       (case when max(DC) is null and max(CC) is null then 1 else 0 end) as flag1,
       (case when max(DC) is not null and max(CC) is null then 1 else 0 end) as flag2,
       max(case when PtCls = 'E' then 1 else 0 end) as flag3,
       max(case when PtCls = 'E' then 0 else 1 end) as flag4
from table t
group by VisitID;
```

Next, re-aggregate this:

```
select sum(flag1) as cnt1, sum(flag2) as cnt2, sum(flag3) as cnt3, sum(flag4) as cnt4
from (select VisitID,
             (case when max(DC) is null and max(CC) is null then 1 else 0 end) as flag1,
             (case when max(DC) is not null and max(CC) is null then 1 else 0 end) as flag2,
             max(case when PtCls = 'E' then 1 else 0 end) as flag3,
             max(case when PtCls = 'E' then 0 else 1 end) as flag4
      from table t
      group by VisitID
     ) v;
```

You can remove a group where Ptcls is never E by using `exists`:

```
select t.*
from table t
where exists (select 1
              from table t2
              where t2.visitId = t.visitId and
                    t2.PtCls = 'E'
             );
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked perfectly EXCEPT for the patient class part. Then I changed it to: 

(case when MAX(PtCls) = 'E' then 1 else 0 end) as flag7,
(case when MAX(PtCls) = 'E' then 0 else 1 end) as flag8
from table t

otherwise, the visits with ptcls=E at some point, and those that never have ptcls=E don't add up with the total visits. 

Thank you so much!!